# Dynamically call web service secured with WS-Security

Tags: web-services, wcf, security, ws-security

I am working on a client side software written in .Net 4.5.1. The software supports invoking different web services, some of them are secured by WS-Security, some of them are not.

Are there any ways I can send some requests with WS-Security embedded, and some requests not?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Each service you call has its own configuration section in the application's configuration file.

Below is an example `app.config` copied from [the MSDN article 'Client Configuration'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731745(v=vs.110).aspx). Notice how each service you call has an `endpoint` element, and that each `endpoint` element can reference `binding` configurations. The WS-security configuration is done on the binding elements, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731362(v=vs.110).aspx) for documentation on WCF security. Basically you have to set security mode to `Message` to use WS-security encryption of requests and responses.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
        <client>
          <endpoint
            name="endpoint1"
            address="http://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IHello"
            behaviorConfiguration="IHello_Behavior"
            contract="IHello" >

            <metadata>
              <wsdlImporters>
                <extension
                  type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.WsdlDocumentationImporter, WsdlDocumentation"/>
              </wsdlImporters>
            </metadata>

            <identity>
              <servicePrincipalName value="host/localhost" />
            </identity>
          </endpoint>
// Add another endpoint by adding another <endpoint> element.
          <endpoint
            name="endpoint2">
           //Configure another endpoint here.
          </endpoint>
        </client>

//The bindings section references by the bindingConfiguration endpoint attribute.
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IHello" 
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"/>
          <reliableSession ordered="true" 
                           enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
           //Security settings go here.
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="Another Binding"
        //Configure this binding here.
        </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

//The behavior section references by the behaviorConfiguration endpoint attribute.
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name=" IHello_Behavior ">
                    <clientVia />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I will not know what services ahead of time. Users can provide a service through UI and we will discover the provided service, and invoke the specific method of that service user selected. Some of this invoke needs WS-Security, but some don't

Comment: OK, in that case you will have to create the endpoint, binding and behavior objects in code.

Comment: I will only able to know what service I am connecting to at runtime, I found the way to create endpoint and binding in code if the I knew the service ahead of time. However, if I do not know the service, I found a way to call web services with reflection, similar to this post: https://vaibhavgaikwad.wordpress.com/web-services-with-reflection-in-net/. But I dont know how to support WS-Security in this case